# how to shift a parameter and throw it entirely from args ls?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a script that gets N params. It first parses them (extracts a specific value `X`), then calls another program with said value:

```
function main() {
    parse "$@"
    run "$@"
}
main "$@"
```

I want to add an optional param at the start of the args list (param to set the python version I'm running).
So I added this to the parse functoin:

```
if [ "$1" = '2' ] || [ "$1" = '3' ]; then version=$1 && shift; else version=2; fi
```

However, after the parse ends, I'm stuck because the `shift` doesn't affect the run function. How can I do this without checking again the value of the first value (which would defeat the whole purpose of having a parse function)

Comment: `$@` is expanded to its value before parse is called, so it never sees `$@` but only its contents. You'll have to `shift` in your main function or pass `${@:2}` (if you're using bash). If parse doesn't output anything yet, you could echo the remaining parameters and call parse like `params=$(parse "$@") `. BTW this looks like a shell script, why the python tag?

Comment: @danzel thx! I thought about your 2 suggestions already... `shift` in main means I don't use the parse function (which I like) and passing the result of parse to run didn't work for me, as the original code uses it in a weird way... (the Py tag was a mistake)

Comment: I guess you could return an integer shift index from the `parse` function, and perform the actual shift in the main body (i.e. `parse "$@"; shift $?`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of each shell function (as well as the scope of top-level code in the script) has its own [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters), and can only directly access its own. The cleanest solution is to place the values of the positional parameters you're interested in into [an *array*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays). You can then read, and also modify, that array in multiple function scopes.

For example, you could have this code appear near the beginning of your script:

```
declare -a args=("$@")
```

- Name the array however you like--it doesn't have to be called `args`.
- You can even omit `declare -a`, if you want.
- It doesn't really need to appear near the beginning. It just has to *run* before any of the code that accesses `args` runs. It could even appear below the definitions of shell functions that use `args`. For clarity, I suggest putting it somewhere near the beginning.

Then you can operate on the `args` array from multiple functions. You don't have to pass it to the functions; they will already be able to access it. When code in a shell function modifies the contents of `args` and then returns, code in the caller will be able to observe the changes.

Positional parameters in Bourne-style shells, including Bash, use 1-based indexing. (This is because `$0`, which expands to the program name, is technically not a positional parameter, and does not change in function scopes.) But arrays in Bash use 0-based indexing. So, after `args=("$@")`, `$1` matches `${args[0]}`, `$2` matches `${args[1]}`, `$3` matches `${args[2]}`, and so forth. `$@` still matches `${args[@]}` as you would expect.

I wrote them that way, unquoted, for readability. You will, of course, almost always want to double-quote expansions involving your `args` array, just as you'd almost always want to double-quote expansions involving positional parameters.

If you decide to go with this approach, then instead of:

```
shift
```

You would write:

```
args=("${args[@]:1}")
```

If you're new to arrays in Bash, you'll want to take a look at [the relevant part of the Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays). You may also want to experiment interactively. For example:

```
ek@Cord:~$ args=('foo bar' 'baz quux' 'ham spam')
ek@Cord:~$ printf '[%s]\n' "${args[@]}"
[foo bar]
[baz quux]
[ham spam]
ek@Cord:~$ printf '[%s]\n' "${args[@]:1}"
[baz quux]
[ham spam]
```

The code corresponding to

```
if [ "$1" = 2 ] || [ "$1" = 3 ]; then
    version="$1"
    shift
else
    version=2
fi
```

would be:

```
if [ "${args[0]}" = 2 ] || [ "${args[0]}" = 3 ]; then
    version="${args[0]}"
    args=("${args[@]:1}")
else
    version=2
fi
```

Using an array is syntactically more cumbersome, but also more flexible.

On the other hand, since you seem to have most of the code of your script organized into a `run` function and its callees anyway, you might consider the alternative of parsing any special command-line arguments *before* calling `run`, outside of any shell function, and then calling `run "$@"` as you're already doing.

There are programming languages whose associated cultures have a strong ethic of putting almost everything into small(ish), self-contained functions. Bash is not such a language, and the limited ways of returning complex data from a shell function is one of the reasons. You shouldn't be afraid to write shell functions, and you should even be willing to write a huge number of tiny shell functions. But I don't think you should be worried if it turns out that the best form for your script is something else.

**For further reading, and some alternatives including a weird approach where you source the output of process substitution, see [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/51866/11938) to [Function caller positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50654/function-caller-positional-parameters).**